# Use the value (ID) of a field as a reference in a lookup field's condition

Tags: ms-access

How can I use the value (ID) of a field as a reference in a lookup field's condition in MS Access?

Example table1 schema:

```
ID (Number)
Name (Char)
ID_Something (Number)
...
Lookup1 (Number)
```

The field Lookup1 uses a condition like this:

```
[...] WHERE table2.myID = table1.ID_Something
```

How can I force the lookup field use the value of the field ID_Something and automatically update if changed?
Please not that I want to achieve that without any forms, just the plain table.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When a field is looking up to another table. It should **JOIN** them to bring the value and not the ID. Your Query should be something like.

```
SELECT 
    table1.fieldName1,
    table1.fieldName2,
    table2.fieldName1
FROM 
    table1 INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.commonID = table2.commonID;
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I don't want to join the query. Instead I just want to limit the input values of a lookup field according to a foreign key constraint.

Comment: In other words you want this column to be a calculation? I would strongly suggest you not to go ahead with this. Just drop the Lookup column and only store the base value. When you need the value you can get it on the dot, when you do this JOIN.

Comment: Once again, I don't want to join something. And I don't want to calculate something. I just want to limit the values in a lookup field according to the _current_ selection of another field. Without creating any form mumbo-jumbo. Just in the plain table view.

Comment: A column dependency is in other words calculation. What you say is not going to be easily possible without making some sort of compromise. Anyway, Good luck.